# Normal Distribution and PDF

Tags: probability, statistics

If $X$ has a normal distribution with parameters $(\mu, \sigma^2)$, what is the density of $Y = cX$, assuming $c$ to be a constant ?

Comment: $$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{|c|}f_X\left(\frac{y}{c}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $X$ has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then $Y=cX$ has mean $c\mu$ and variance $c^2\sigma^2$.

(In fact, these are more general results: this is true of *any* random variable $X$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.)

So, simply plug this new mean/variance in to the usual density formula for a normal variable:
$$
f_Y(x)=\frac{\exp\left[-\frac{(x-c\mu)^2}{2c^2\sigma^2}\right]}{\lvert c\rvert\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}.
$$
(The absolute values come from being careful: in general, $\sqrt{c^2}=\lvert c\rvert$.)

Comment: You have jumped the gun a bit here in that you already _assumed_ that $Y$ is a normal random variable and so just replacing $\mu$ by $c\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ by $c^2\sigma^2$ in the formula for the normal density will give the density of $Y$. Of course, $Y$ _is_ a normal random variable but this needs proving once (and then remembering the fact that $aX+b$ is normal if $X$ is for the rest of one's life).

Answer (score 0):

Another way: use change of variable approach to get 
$$
\frac{dX}{dy}=\frac{1}{c}\\
f_{X}(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2c^2}}
$$
Hence 
$$
f_{Y}(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2c^2}}\bigg|\frac{dX}{dy}\bigg|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi c^2}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2c^2}}
$$
Hence $Y \sim N(0,c^2)$